# how to use a jndi property file to use a service deployed in a distant server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi

I have  a server  ejb (ofc  deployed on the server) and I want to use it in an other client ejb app by adding it as a dependency and then calling it in the main function.
Here is the code :

```
package mavensayhelloclient;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import sayhellopackage.SayhelloRemote;

public abstract class Testclient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InitialContext cx = new InitialContext();
    Object obj = 
    cx.lookup("mavensayhelloproject/Sayhello!sayhello
    package.SayhelloRemote");
    SayhelloRemote proxy = (SayhelloRemote) obj;
    System.out.println(proxy.sayHello("4infoB2"));
}

}
```

I am using a jndi  proprety file which is in src/main/resources package (maven  project) :

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:18080
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
```

But I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException:
>   Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an
>   applet parameter, or in an application resource file: 
>   java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: Did you name the properties file `jndi.properties` and is it on the classpath?

Comment: it is  under  the src/main/resources  package  i dont  have  a classpath package ! 
and  yes  the  name  is  jndi.properties

Comment: Are you starting the application right from your IDE or from an jar? This should work if the `jndi.properties` file is on your classpath. Maybe try to set the properties directly in your code just to test if the connection is working at all.

Comment: hi , yes  i m  starting  it right  from  the IDE (jboss) 
yes  it  works  when  i   set  the properties directly  in  my code ,
do you have  any idea  why  ?

Comment: It needs to be in the root of the CLASSPATH, not in the 'resources` directory.

Answer (score -1):

When you have some weird errors with eclipse, go to your project :

1) remove .settings and .profile and .classpath

2) delete the project from workspace

3) import the project as maven project